# Keep intermediate files only on failure

Tags: gnu-make

I've got a chained rule in my Makefile:

```
%.int: %.src
        preprocess -i $< -o $@

%.dst: %.int
        compile -i $< -o $@

SRCS=$(wildcard *.src)
DSTS=$(patsubst %.src,$.dst,$(SRCS))

all: $(DSTS)
```

It preprocesses `.src` to `.int`, and then compiles `.int` to `.dst`.

It works fine, except that GNU Make always deletes the intermediate files.

That's fine; I read [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html); I understand why it does that. I know that I can keep them around if I use `.PRECIOUS` or `.SECONDARY` pseudo-targets.

However, what I'd like to do is keep the intermediate file **if and only if** the `int2dst` step failed. Basically, I'd like to see what mess the preprocessor left me with.

Can I do that with GNU Make?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, though perhaps not a pretty one, would be to go ahead and put those files into `.PRECIOUS`, but then manually delete from the build rule:

```
%.dst: %.int
        compile -i $< -o $@
        rm $<
```